# Adding text after a bullet (or adding text in itemize)

Tags: itemize

I am trying to figure out how I should add text after a bullet point.

Meaning say

1. Project 1 (this is the bullet)
   (Its Description , is the text I am talking about)
2. Project 2 
   Next Description

Also , Is there anyway to change the spacing between two bullets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\star$}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}
\selectfont
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
%[ansinew]
[utf8]
{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\textheight=9.75in
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-2 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.5cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{-0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.62in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}
\hspace{0.5cm}\\[-0.2cm]

\textbf{Anupam Bisht} \\
\indent $2^{nd}$ Year, B.Tech Student\\
\indent Electrical and Electronics Engineering
\hfill Ph: +91 7200660151\\
\indent VIT University, Vellore, TN -632014
\hfill Email: anupam.bisht2015@vit.ac.in \\

\resheading{\textbf{OBJECTIVE} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{4mm} \vfill
\indent To obtain a job in a core-company so that the technical skills and the knowledge acquired during the past \indent can  be used to develop a new solution or optimize existing solutions for the profit of company as well as \indent betterment of the society.

\vspace{2mm}
\resheading{\textbf{ACADEMIC DETAILS} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{5mm} \vfill
%\begin{table}[ht!]
%\begin{center}
\indent \begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l }
\hline
\vspace{0.1mm}
\textbf{Year} &\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institute}   & \textbf{CGPA/\%} \\
\hline
2015- Present&B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering & VIT Vellore  & 9.69 CGPA \\

2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 94.8\%\\

2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 10 CGPA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
%\end{table}
\vspace{2mm}

%\resheading{\textbf{FIELDS OF INTEREST} }\\[\lsep]
%\begin{itemize}
%\item \noindent Wireless Network and Network Security, %Another one, a third one
%\end{itemize}
\resheading{\textbf{AREA OF INTEREST} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{1.0mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Medical Sensors, circuit design, computer interfacing of hardware, control systems.
\end{itemize}
\vfill

\resheading{\textbf{TECHNICAL SKILLS} }\\[\lsep]
\vfill \vspace{1.0mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent \textbf{Languages:\space} C ,\space C++,\space Python, \space R
\item \noindent \textbf{Tools:\space}MATLAB,\space Orcad Pspice,\space Arduino\space, LabView ,\space\LaTeX
\item \noindent \textbf{Platforms:\space} Linux and Windows
\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{PROJECTS} }\\[\lsep]
\vfill \vspace{0.5mm}
\begin{itemize}\itemsep2pt
\item \textbf{Calculation of HeartBeat using Photoplethysmogram in LabVIEW.} \textit{(Feburary 2017 - Currently Working)}
\end{itemize}
\indent We have designed to algorithms, which are inspired from the Pan-Tompkins Algorithm for QRS waveform detection for calculation of heartbeat. We also trying to do statistical analysis of the data using the R software


\resheading{\textbf{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent  A volunteer at Kulethi primary school Champawat,Uttarakhand. I helped to promote tablet assisted teaching in the primary school.Also helped in video making of basic science experiments in Hindi, which are uploaded in YouTube.(June 2016)

\item \noindent  Core Committee member at IEEE student chapter of VIT University.
(October 2015 - March 2016)

\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{ACHIEVEMENTS} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for ranking 3rd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2016-17.

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for ranking 2nd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2015-16.

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for scoring 10 CGPA in class 10th Board Examination.

\item \noindent  Selected to represent KVS for Jawaharlal Nehru National Science, Mathematics and Environment Exhibition for children(JNNSMEE) held at Gangtok, Sikkim during November 2013.

\item \noindent  Awarded 3rd Prize at KVS National Level Science Exhibition held at Kendriya Vidiyalaya Ballygunge, Kolkata for the project titled "Principle of Fiber Optic Communication and Related  Applications" in the year 2012.

\end{itemize}


%\resheading{\textbf{MAJOR PROJECTS AND SEMINAR} }\\[\lsep]
%\begin{itemize}
%\item \textbf{Media Access Control Controling
%} (Research Project) \\
% \emph{(Guide:Prof. Hubert F.
%, May'13 - till date)} \\[-0.6cm]
%   \begin{itemize}\itemsep \isep
%   \item Objective :Performance analysis of HTTP web browsing traffic.
%.
%   \item Performance analysis will help in comparing different MAC protocols based on different network sce-
%narios.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you use `\item`  or `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` at all?

Comment: Would you please add some code what you've got.

Comment: I think plainTeX would have suited you more.

Comment: This is a huge example. Which part is relevant to the question?

Comment: I must say I don't understand what you want to achieve.  To add some text after a bullet, well… add it! Where's the problem?

Comment: your document should not have any `\noindent` and vary rarely `\\ ` or `\vspace` , nor do you need any of the `\space` commands that you have there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I understood the description of your questions, but I have no idea how the code you added might be related your question, I did not see anything about projects or similar.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Project 1 \textbullet\ (Its Description, is the text I am talking about)
    \item Project 2 Next Description
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulation. You got the tick, so it seems this really is what the OP expected. Out for a while trying to pick up the pieces of my broken sanity.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks! The trick was to ignore everything after the first 3 lines of the questions as I did not see how the rest could be connected to the question :) I hope you have enough super glue to piece together your sanity :)